# Using custom mime type for drag'n'drop events or data attribute dilema

Tags: javascript, html5

I am having a dilema on a html/js application I have been requestyed to handle drag'n'drop events in order to display a dropped image in a `div` if is not from images that are already displayed in my app then upload them as well.

My problem is how I will know if is an in-app image or not?

A sample code that describes the problem is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Drag'n'Drop demo</title>

        <style>
            #dropArea{
                min-width:50%;
                min-height:800px;
                background-color:#FF00BB;
                float: left;
            }

            #imgArea {
                min-width:49%;
                min-height:800px;
                background-color:#0F0FBB;
                float: right;
            }

            #imgArea img {
                display:block;
                margin:5px;
            }

        </style>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
          var onDropCallback=function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");

            if(data){
               console.log("External Image Droped: ",  data); 
            } else {
                data = event.dataTransfer.getData("application/sample");
                console.log("In app droped: ", data);
            }

          }

          var dragSrart=function(event){
            // alert("DragStarted")
            console.log("Drag Started");
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
            event.dataTransfer.clearData();
            event.dataTransfer.setData('application/sample',data);
          }

          var ondragoverCallback=function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var elem=event.target || event.srcElement;
            $(elem).css('border',"1px solid black");
          }

          var dragEndCallback=function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Drag End HAppened");
            $("#dropArea").css('border',"none");
          }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dropArea" ondragover="ondragoverCallback(event)" ondrop="onDropCallback(event)" ></div>
        <div id="imgArea">
            <img draggable="true" ondragstart="dragSrart(event)" ondragend="dragEndCallback(event)" src="https://kazasou.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/g288.gif">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This above for the problem is that I use custom mime type. But is it a good idea I mean what problems may cause this approach?

Also I have thought an alternate approach of using html5's `data-` attributes on images eg `data-app`:

```js
 <img draggable="true" ondragstart="dragSrart(event)" ondragend="dragEndCallback(event)" src="https://kazasou.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/g288.gif" data-app>
```

So on drop I can check the html if has the correct `data-` attribute. But I am in delema which one is the best one. May I have some help?

Answer (score -1):

> My problem is how I will know if is an in-app image or not?

Image comparison can be done by using the HTML5 Canvas to compare pixels. For [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/compare-2-images):

```
 function compareImages(img1, img2, pixelCount) {
   for (var i = 0; i < pixelCount; ++i) {
      if (img1.data[i] !== img2.data[i]) {
           return false;
        }
   }
   return true;
}
```

**References**

- [javascript - how to compare two different images in java script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741720/how-to-compare-two-different-images-in-java-script)